# Focus on search doesn't work

Tags: html, css, focus

I want to do code which will show input field for Search when user clicks on Search icon. I wrote it but it doesn't work. I tried with :active and :hover and nothing. I think the problem is in class with >

```
#_hsync_pretraga_polje {
    padding-top: 8px;
    display: none;
}

._hsync_pretrtaga:focus > #_hsync_pretraga_polje {
    display: block;
}

<li>
    <a class="_hsync_pretrtaga"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
    <a id="_hsync_pretraga_polje"><input type="text" class="form-control _hsync_reg_input" style="margin: 0;" id="_hsync_pretraga" placeholder="Pretraga korisnika"></a>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

I made this and nothing. `<a>` is in `<li>`. CSS code is same

```
<a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" class="_hsync_pretrtaga"></span>
    <input type="text" id="_hsync_pretraga_polje" class="form-control _hsync_reg_input" style="margin: 0;" id="_hsync_pretraga" placeholder="Pretraga korisnika">
</a>
```

Comment: It´s hidden...the focus will only work if is visible!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change other element on focus or on hover of one element, you have to use JS, because you can only change child element like that in CSS.

Comment: Actually, he could set the `:focus` on the parent element (the `<li>` element), and there set the child element to `display: block`: Something like this: `li:focus ._hsync_pretrtaga { display: block; }`. This way, wherever you have the focus on the whole element, that'll keep the search field in `display: block`.

Comment: I don't understand what is "child element"

Comment: A child element is for example the anchor `<a>` element, and the parent element is the list `<li>` element. See, the `<li>` has a `<a>` inside. That's how we reference the relations between nested elements.

Comment: Yes, he could set :focus on parent element, that's what I said, and he can that change properties of child elements, but there is no way he could affect parent or siblings with CSS

Comment: Coming to think about it... Not sure `<li>` is even focusable. Not every element can receive `focus`. I know that anchors and inputs can, but that might be a bit more complicated than what I've written above.

Comment: I did some changes in frist post/question.